# ES 5.2 - DateHistogram aggregration query issue with timestamp field as long type

Tags: elasticsearch

We are facing one issue related to histogram aggregation while upgrading from 2.2 to 5.2. We are storing timestamp field as a 'long' data type

DateHistogram Aggregation query

```
"aggregations" : {    
"datehistogram" : {    
"date_histogram" : {     
"field" : "timestamp",     
"time_zone" : "+05:30",       
"interval" : "minute",     
"offset" : 0,     
"order" : {      
"_key" : "asc"     
},    
"keyed" : false,       
"min_doc_count" : 0     
}     
}      

This query was working well with ES 2.2 version. But with ES 5.2 its throwing below error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field [timestamp] of type [long] does not support custom time zones
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.NumberFieldMapper$NumberFieldType.docValueFormat(NumberFieldMapper.java:953) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2].

By changing type of timestamp field from 'long' to 'date' aggregation query works well. But it will require re-indexing of old data and we are looking option to avoid it.

Is there any other way for histogram aggregation query to work without changing data type of field ?
```